# Rename the [curator] tag to [apache-curator], distinguish it from Elasticsearch's Curator

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator) tag is misnamed. It really should be [apache-curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-curator),
 like [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper).

It's causing confusion as people are tagging questions regarding Elasticsearch's Curator with `curator`. Thoughts about renaming?

Comment: It's their fault to not read the tag info page.

Comment: Typical: blame the end-user instead of terrible design. No thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<sup>Please feel free to edit this answer when you decide to work on this and have made some progress.</sup>

<s>Proposed</s> Current plan of attack:

1. Retag [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch+curator) tagged [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) and [curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator) to use [elasticsearch-curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-curator).
   *(<s>8</s> <s>0</s> <s>7</s> 0 questions at the time of writing)*
   [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): thank you [John](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/95852/john-y)!
2. Repeat step 1 for the [elasticsearch-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-5)<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-5+curator)</sup> and [elasticsearch-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-6)<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-6+curator)</sup> tags.
   *(<s>0</s> <s>2</s> 0 questions at the time of writing)*
   [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
3. Deal with [remaining questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator+-apache+-elasticsearch+-apache-zookeeper) manually.
   It looks to me like all of these should also use [apache-curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-curator), but I'm no expert.
   *(<s>13</s> 0 questions at the time of writing)*
   [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
4. Rename [curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator) → [apache-curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-curator).
   [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
5. Optionally add a synonym. Will need to evaluate if users try to reintroduce [curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator).
   [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the meantime, I proposed an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19374135) to the tag excerpt of [curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curator) to discourage its use.

Comment: Would it be proper to keep [tag:elasticsearch] on a question which is tagged [tag:elasticsearch-curator]? (In other words, are we collapsing two tags into one, or just replacing the one ambiguous tag with the one clearer tag?)

Comment: Good question. I think it would be beneficial to keep the elasticsearch tag for greater visibility, @John.

Comment: How does the rename take place? Do I need to do anything else so that a moderator takes action?

Comment: @Randgalt it's a manual process.

Comment: Well, I did step 1. I think [tag:apache-curator] needs to be created in order to proceed with step 3. Alternatively, I believe if step 4 can be accomplished, then that will automatically take care of step 3.

Comment: I created [tag:apache-curator] and started applying it. However, all my updates require peer review which makes me think I lack the perms to do this and someone else should do it. However, I can continue if it's appropriate.

Comment: I would let others handle it, @Randgalt, or at the very least only do a small number of questions at a time.

Comment: I'm starting to see many posts tagged with both `curator` and `apache-curator`. Is this OK with folks? Can step 4 (rename) get accelerated?

Comment: I retagged the last questions from step 3. The rename can now be done as a batch job, I think. Would need a moderator if I'm not mistaken ...

Answer (score 12):

I see value in renaming this tag, as it keeps with the apache-* theme we have going for any of the Apache projects already.  It also helps reduce the likelihood that someone would think that "curator" is a bad tag and needs to be burninated.