# Create new tag [netflix-conductor]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I would like to create a new tag [netflix-conductor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-conductor) for questions regarding the [Netflix Conductor project](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/).
According to its documentation, Netflix Conductor is:

> An orchestration engine that runs in the cloud

Suggested wiki:

> An open source orchestration library for micro services orchestration in the cloud. Allows the creation and execution of scalable complex workflows with emphasis on Dev Ops management.

The convention seems correct as per other Netflix tags, e.g. [netflix-zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-zuul) and [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka).

Sample questions that would benefit from the tag:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090042/netflix-conductor-sqs),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178225/running-netflix-conductor-with-standalone-elastic-search),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903352/how-do-i-register-a-microservice-or-its-methods-to-task-in-netflix-conductor).

Also, I see some questions wrongly tagged as [conductor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conductor), the Android one:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336438/how-to-test-netflix-conductor-workflows),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503759/using-kafka-with-netflix-conductor).

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363983).

Comment: Could you provide a initial tag excerpt and wiki as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)?

Comment: thanks, have updated question with details

Comment: Looks good to me. I'll go ahead and create it for you. (there are only 4 tagged questions so we can always remove it if the community doesn't think this is a good idea)

Comment: By the way, I see that of the questions listed, all of them are from last year. If there isn't going to be much activity in this tag, then I don't think the tag should stay. Only time will tell.

Comment: I would reject that suggested excerpt because it doesn't describe **why you would use the tag**. In fact, it only describes the service

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think tag activity shouldn't be a relevant factor in tag criteria just because a tag isn't frequently used doesn't mean it doesn't deserve to be a tag, look at the [colorama](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/colorama/info) that doesn't get much use, but using the tag helps make it identifiable to people who are knowledgeable

Comment: @Machavity FWIW It _does_ say "Allows the creation and execution of scalable complex workflows with emphasis on Dev Ops management." which is embellished language but definitely a reason I'd use it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is this something for use with the Netflix service, tho? Or is this some tool that Netflix just created? The excerpt should explain that

Comment: @Machavity Reading the docs, it looks like a tool Netflix created and the open sourced... I could be wrong though, yeah needs a bit more polishing.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint of a tag that has hardly been used or is going to be?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ both, frequency of use shouldn't be a deciding factor at creation or even burnination

Comment: Oh good, the excerpt was used verbatim, despite [@Machavity's warning against it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367923/create-new-tag-netflix-conductor#comment590076_367923)... :(